# Calling a Bean Function in a JavaScript if statement for eveluating Primefaces object

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using Primefaces Schedule and I am using  which has a listener parameter of `org.primefaces.event.DateSelectEvent`. 
Based on whether DateSelectEvent.getDate is a weekeday or a weekend, I need to open a dialog box or just disable ajax (or don't do anything). For that I need to make a decision in the oncompelete attribute of . I have gone as far as this:

```
<p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{myBean.onDateSelect}" oncomplete="
       if (onDateSelect.getDate == WeekDay) { 
           eventDialog.show()
       } else {
           myschedule.update()
       }"
>
```

Well, obviously `onDateSelect.getDate == Weekday` doesn't work and must be taken care of by a function on my backing bean, but how can I evaluate my backing bean method in JS function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `oncomplete` attribute of PrimeFaces components doesn't support evaluating requestbased EL expressions. One of the ways is to use [`RequestContext#execute()`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.5/org/primefaces/context/RequestContext.html#execute%28java.lang.String%29) inside `onDateSelect` listener method instead of a `oncomplete`.

```
RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();

if (isWeekDay(onDateSelect.getDate())) { 
    requestContext.execute("eventDialog.show()");
} else {
    requestContext.execute("myschedule.update()");
}
```

Another way is to ajax-update a `<h:outputScript>` block containing the desired EL expressions.

```
<p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{myBean.onDateSelect}" update="script" />
...
<h:panelGroup id="script">
    <h:outputScript>
        if (#{myBean.weekDaySelected}) { 
            eventDialog.show()
        } else {
            myschedule.update()
        }
    </h:outputScript>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: You saved me again! Thank you! 
You are correct and I needed something that is evaluated after ajax call is made and not when document loads!!

Answer (score 0):

As per the requirement you've mentioned I believe you are looking for something with which you can use a `Javascript` function and invoke your backing bean `method` to evaluate if its a weekday.

You can use Ajax4jsf's `a4j:jsFunction` like:

```
<p:ajax event="dateSelect" 
        listener="#{myBean.onDateSelect}" 
        oncomplete="checkWeekDay"/>

<a4j:jsFunction name="checkWeekDay" action="#{beanName.methodName}"/>
```

Comment: OP is using PrimeFaces which has `<p:remoteCommand>` out the box for the same purpose as `<a4j:jsFunction>`. Why are you recommending the `<a4j:jsFunction>` then?

Comment: @BalusC My bad, I didn't knew PrimeFaces too has something like this !

Comment: @dShringi thank you for your answer however, I had already tried that and as BalusC had mentioned in his answer, these types of JS are evaluated when document loads. What I am specifically asking is a JS that is evaluated after ajax request is made

Answer (score 0):

You can use EL in the javascript commands too. So I assume you have method named isWeekDay similar to folowing, or just use your own function to determine whether the date is a week day or not:

```
public boolean isWeekDay()
{
     Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
     c.setTime(yourDate);
     return c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) < 5;
}

<p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{myBean.onDateSelect}" oncomplete="
       if (#{yourBean.weekDay()}) { 
           eventDialog.show()
       } else {
           myschedule.update()
       }"
>
```

Comment: That EL is only evaluated when rendering the form, not after the form submit and thus all bean properties are literally "one behind".